# Connecting Golang pipes and Python 2.7

Tags: python, go

I have following task: need connecting Go pipe with Python. I understand how run pythonic process under Go:

```
var compiler string = "python"
var path string = "...here script path"
pyExec := exec.Command(compiler, path)
pyExecIn, _ := pyExec.StdinPipe()
pyExecOut, _ := pyExec.StdoutPipe()
pyExec.Start()
// acitions
pyExec.Wait()
```

I can write data in stdin but I read it only after terminating script.
For get data inside process I decide use pipe, but I only can write message into pythonic script. When Go trying read data from python process is blocked. Answer me please, this is trouble with implementation or Goland pipes and pythonic pipes not compatible? Exist another way connection both process (except socket and so on)

Go:

```
var compiler string = "python"
var path string = "...here script path"
pyExec := exec.Command(compiler, path)
pyExecIn, _ := pyExec.StdinPipe()
pyExecOut, _ := pyExec.StdoutPipe()
pipeReader, pipeWriter := io.Pipe()
pyExec.Stdin = pipeReader
pyExec.Stdout = pipeWriter
pyExec.Start()
pipeWriter.Write(message)
var received_data = make([]byte, 1024)
data, _ := pipeReader.Read(received_data)
pyExecIn.Close()
pyExecOut.Close()
pyExec.Wait()
```

Python:

```
r, w = os.pipe()
r = os.fdopen(r, 'r')
raw_responce = r.read(1024)
# actions
w = os.fdopen(w, 'w')
w.write(data)
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you want to use pipes at all since you have direct access to standard io in Go. As you can see what you're referring to is a `os.pipe()`... Like  `|` in Bash, which composes two commands, sending the output from the first as input to the second. But to accomplish the same in Go you just read on stdout and then call the next command with the data in that `io.Reader`, no pipes involved.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks. But it`s not only simple calling pythonic script and his immediately terminated, this exactly client part which in future will coding in C# or C++. All action in scripts accomplish in infinity loop how in Go (server side). So I needed communicated in running proces. Or I don`t undestand you approach?